# Universally lock the orientation of MKMoviePlayerController to landscape mode only

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape

How to use MPMoviePlayerController to play video in landscape orientation in iOS all across the Application. I am using the MPMoviePlayerController in many viewControllers of my app and I want all the MKMoviePlayerController torun only in landscape mode irrespective of the orientation of the parent view controller from where this ViewController is called.

Answer (score 1):

Enable landscape orientation in your project settings.

Subclass UIViewController and in your new subclass (e.g. MyViewController) add these callbacks:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Make all your view controllers of type MyViewController.

In the views you want to force landscape override those methods with:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```